# How do I force inclusion of empty directories when copying a file tree using gradle 0.8?

Tags: gradle

Using Gradle 0.8, I have the following file structure

```
source/
  stuff/
    file.txt
  empty/
```

Which I want copied to create

```
target/
  stuff/
    file.txt
  empty/
```

So I tried this:

```
  def sourceTree = fileTree(dir: 'source')
  def targetDir = file(dir: 'target')

  copy {
    from sourceTree 
    into targetDir
  }
```

But instead I end up with:

```
target/
  stuff/
    file.txt
```

How do I force inclusion of empty directories?

Answer (score -1):

I am having a wild guess here but can you try

```
def sourceTree = fileTree(dir: 'source').include('**/*')
```